# github line endings in a mess

Tags: git, github

OK so its my own fault due to lack of knowledge but I made a mess out of my github repository.  I need the code to work on Linux but did some edits from a Windows machine directly in github.com and it seems the line endings are now Windows style.
I tried adding .gitattributes but this has not worked, when I git clone it still comes to my Linux machine with Windows line endings. Using dos2unix works but obviously thats not a proper solution.

How do I edit the repository to make it Linux ready, Im a git noob so need step by step please.

Comment: `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Comment: And that will change the version on github?

Comment: There is a lot of information if you do a search: [git line endings](https://www.google.com/search?q=git%20line%20endings). You can change you *client* software to automatically convert to a "neutral" setting for storage and OS specific in your working copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer was:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Modify the somefile.py in an arbitrary way, then:

```
git add somefile.py
git commit
git push
```

Now GitHub has the correct line endings.